# Angular 8/Nodemailer - Contact Form function not logging errors, no email received

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using an Angular 8/Firebase stack and I have a contact form that writes to my Firestore collection. This works fine. I have also written a cloud function that triggers on write of the database and fires off a nodemailer email to my personal email.

The issue is that I never get any emails even though the cloud function logger seems to be going off every time I submit a test contact form. No errors logged, but none of my console.logs get recorded either.

I've allowed less secure apps and disabled captchas on the Gmail I'm using to send email (even though I don't use 2FA). Still nothing. Now, I'm at a loss as to what could be going on since I have no logs to work with.

Here's my cloud function index.js:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
const gmailEmail = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.email);
const gmailPassword = encodeURIComponent(functions.config().gmail.password);
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
  smtpTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: `${gmailEmail}`,
      pass: `${gmailPassword}`
    }
  })
);

exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
  .ref('/messages/{pushKey}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    if (snapshot.previous.val() || !snapshot.val().name) {
      return;
    }

    const val = snapshot.val();

    const mailOptions = {
      from: `${gmailEmail}`,
      to: 'donotreply@something.com',
      subject: `You've been contacted by ${val.name} ✨`,
      text: `${val.message}`
    };
    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error occurred');
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    });
  });
```

The trigger itself seems to be working since I see Firebase logs (but not console.logs) in the console every time I hit submit on the contact form. I think it's an issue with SMTP or my mailTransport object. I've tried quite a few different formats for this object that I found across the web but nothing.

Note: The string interpolated variables for my Gmail and password I've set via the Firebase CLI and they log correctly when I run the command to retrieve them. It's not a credentials issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't mixing-up a Cloud Function trigger for the Realtime Database with a trigger for Firestore. They are two different NoSQL Database services offered by Firebase.

    `exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
      .ref('/messages/{pushKey}')
      .onWrite(...)`

 is for declaring a trigger for the Realtime Database, but you indicate that you write to Firestore.

Comment: Interesting, that could be the case. But if it were, why would writing to my Firestore actually trigger the cloud function and output logs?

Comment: I have the same question! :-)  But do you confirm that you use Firestore (with collections and documents) and not the Realtime Database?

Comment: You only have one Cloud Function declared. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes. I just changed the code to 

`functions.firestore.document('messages/{pushKey}').onCreate((snap, context) => {})`

and it's logging errors fine now! Thank you! Please add your suggestion as an answer so I can upvote and you can get rep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are mixing-up a Cloud Function trigger for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?authuser=1) with a trigger for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=1). They are two different NoSQL Database services offered by Firebase.

```
exports.sendContactMessage = functions.database
  .ref('/messages/{pushKey}')
  .onWrite(...)
```

is for declaring a trigger for the Realtime Database, but you indicate in your question that you write to Firestore.

So you have to change your function declaration as follows:

```
exports.sendContactMessage = functions.firestore
   .document('messages/{pushKey}')
   .onCreate((snap, context) => {...})
```